# Reversing Engineering of DRM streaming protections

Tags: frida

I read [here](https://mrmoddom.github.io/research/DRM-reversing/) a way to reversing a DRM with Frida and Unicorn. I read also [here](https://how2do.org/sky-now-drm-decryption-keys-leaked-on-the-net-its-a-storm/) about an article of PlayReady DRM 
I wanted to understand these reversing techniques a little better in their general and theoretical aspect

For example, why **Frida** and **Unicorn** are used ? And what other methods you know for DRM reversing (L3 CDM, Widevine, PlayReady, FairPlay, Nagra DRM, Access, Marlin..) ?